# Print returns none even though there its not

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Hey I am trying to **scrape** a website for pricing. It returns `[]` even though on the search page it has a value of $79.99. I only want it to pull the first price from the search page. I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.

```
bburl = "https://www.ebgames.ca/SearchResult/QuickSearch?q=animal+crossing"

def bestbuy():
    proxies = get_proxy()
    result = requests.get(bburl,headers=header,timeout=12,proxies=proxies)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(result.content, 'lxml')

    titles = soup.title
    price = soup.find_all('span',attrs={'class':'megaButton buyTier3 cartAddNoRadio'})

    print(titles)
    print(price)
```

It returns this

```
<title>EB Games | The largest video game retailer in Canada. Play. Trade. Save.  - EBGames.ca </title>
[]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class `megaButton buyTier3 cartAddNoRadio` is in an `a` tag not a `span`.
To only get the first element use `.find()` instead of `find_all()`.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

bburl = "https://www.ebgames.ca/SearchResult/QuickSearch?q=animal+crossing"

def bestbuy():
    result = requests.get(bburl)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(result.content, 'lxml')

    price = soup.find('a',attrs={'class': 'megaButton buyTier3 cartAddNoRadio'})

    print(price.get_text(strip=True, separator=' '))


bestbuy()
```

Outputs:

```
New $79.99
```